# How to sign a XML file with special characters?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have to sign an XML and this returns error "Invalid CAF sign". *(CAF = Código Autorización de Folios)*

I have this XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<AUTORIZACION>
<CAF version="1.0">
<DA>
<RE>76521854-3</RE>
<RS>SOCIEDAD FARMACEUTICA O&quot;HIGGINS SPA</RS>
<TD>33</TD>
<RNG><D>101</D><H>200</H></RNG>
<FA>2020-05-28</FA>
<RSAPK><M>t6ldOQd1Mz+1tiYhaMvVCKeAyT2vQK4rqYCHtbMDWIAHBGwI3mr1mmgLUpXKfvisRl1pTY2RXWdZVd6vE12PSw==</M><E>Aw==</E></RSAPK>
<IDK>100</IDK>
</DA>
<FRMA algoritmo="SHA1withRSA">UQ85YCoqC+pBw7kjzU0g+0uufqKKg759DapDJP4Bt4LMk1mK4330cgBPpVh/iUo5oC9TxINqo0icwFYiAabskw==</FRMA>
</CAF>
<RSASK>-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIBOQIBAAJBALepXTkHdTM/tbYmIWjL1QingMk9r0CuK6mAh7WzA1iABwRsCN5q
9ZpoC1KVyn74rEZdaU2NkV1nWVXerxNdj0sCAQMCQHpw6NCvo3d/znluwPCH41sa
Vdt+dNXJcnEAWnkiAjr+4v/O/o8lhCUGHFaf/0B+1jp2kTnb7b/A4qrd9fxFs7sC
IQDm1L63s29TnXKNkSrlDPGRuqBa0IsmFoXM82Xp0aVhfwIhAMuv9tNUQ1vFbFM/
euaRSNk0CzSmOIanQDhiK9RHT6A1AiEAmeMpz8z04mj3CQtx7gihC9HAPIsHbrmu
iKJD8TZuQP8CIQCHyqSM4teSg52M1PyZtjCQzVzNxCWvGirQQXKNhN/AIwIgXDO7
2/zf8L8fGm6nrDl56Oiybnq0PIg67W4FJ3NBXxI=
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
</RSASK>

<RSAPUBK>-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFowDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSQAwRgJBALepXTkHdTM/tbYmIWjL1QingMk9r0Cu
K6mAh7WzA1iABwRsCN5q9ZpoC1KVyn74rEZdaU2NkV1nWVXerxNdj0sCAQM=
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
</RSAPUBK>
</AUTORIZACION>
```

At `RS` tag we found:

```
<RS>SOCIEDAD FARMACEUTICA O&quot;HIGGINS SPA</RS>
```

For deserialization i use this method with C#:

```
public static T DeserializeRawWithoutEncoding<T>(string filePath)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    T obj;
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
    {
        obj = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        reader.Close();
    }
    return obj;
}
```

But at the moment of desserialize, `&quot;` is transformed to `\"` like in the image:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

I know that both cases are valid because is just an Encoding interpretation.

The final XML signed is like this:

```
<TED version="1.0">
<DD>
<RE>76521854-3</RE>
<TD>33</TD>
<F>101</F>
<FE>2020-05-30</FE>
<RR>66666666-6</RR>
<RSR>Razon Social de Cliente</RSR>
<MNT>0</MNT>
<IT1>Cajón AFECTO</IT1>
<CAF version="1.0">
<DA>
<RE>76521854-3</RE>
<RS>SOCIEDAD FARMACEUTICA O"HIGGINS SPA</RS>
<TD>33</TD>
<RNG>
<D>101</D>
<H>200</H>
</RNG>
<FA>2020-05-28</FA>
<RSAPK>
<M>t6ldOQd1Mz+1tiYhaMvVCKeAyT2vQK4rqYCHtbMDWIAHBGwI3mr1mmgLUpXKfvisRl1pTY2RXWdZVd6vE12PSw==</M>
<E>Aw==</E>
</RSAPK>
<IDK>100</IDK>
</DA>
<FRMA algoritmo="SHA1withRSA">UQ85YCoqC+pBw7kjzU0g+0uufqKKg759DapDJP4Bt4LMk1mK4330cgBPpVh/iUo5oC9TxINqo0icwFYiAabskw==</FRMA>
</CAF>
<TSTED>2020-05-30T20:37:53</TSTED>
</DD>
<FRMT algoritmo="SHA1withRSA">tVLkmiiS4+f2df6VSAuUbtBFzfBREEPu/xY2425y6+GOoBY7RJ44GN0sJOWZV4gqMrVm1bYUFR5PsMFuxyGPQA==</FRMT>
</TED>
```

This XML file is generated when an TED object is serialized by this way:

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
settings.Indent = true;
settings.IndentChars = "";
settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = false;
using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(tempFilePath, settings))
{
      XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());                                                  
      s.Serialize(xmlWriter, obj, ns);
}
```

BUT, `<RS>` tag is written with `\"` instead of `&quot;` and i think that this transformation is the cause of the error.

Actions done without success:

1. Replace `\"` by `&quot;` in a lot of differents ways. Directly with `string.Replace()` or `SecurityElement.Escape()`, hoewever i still getting this error. Also sometimes (according to the replacement done) i get `SOCIEDAD FARMACEUTICA O&amp;quot;HIGGINS SPA`.
2. The serialization and deserialization has been done with ISO-8859-1 Encoding. Ive tried changing this by UTF-8 but without success.

The government institution that is in charge of this, says that [special characters have to be replaced pag. 20](http://www.sii.cl/factura_electronica/instructivo_emision.pdf) but if i do this, i get this error "Invalid CAF sign".

**EDIT**:

Martin Honnen's answer seems to work. But this "final" XML is part of another bigger. When i sign this file `&quot;` character is replaced by `\"`

Code to sign:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
doc.Load(filePath); //path where is the XML file. This XML has &quot; instead of \"

SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(doc);
signedXml.SigningKey = certificado.PrivateKey;
Signature XMLSignature = signedXml.Signature;
Reference reference = new Reference();
reference.Uri = "#" + referenceID;

XmlDsigC14NTransform t = new XmlDsigC14NTransform();
reference.AddTransform(t);            

XMLSignature.SignedInfo.AddReference(reference);
KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
keyInfo.AddClause(new RSAKeyValue((RSA)certificado.PrivateKey));
keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(certificado));
XMLSignature.KeyInfo = keyInfo;
signedXml.ComputeSignature();

XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();
doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(doc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));
doc.Save(filePath); //filepath is overwritten with \" instead of &quot;
```

How to sign this file keeping `&quot;` instead of `\"` in C#?

Comment: In the context of the .NET framework APIs, if you really need to ensure that a double quote character `"` inside of element data is represented by an entity reference `&quot;` I think you need to use your own implementation of XmlWriter that ensures it doesn't write out `"` literally but as `&quot;` using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmltextwriter.writeentityref?view=netcore-3.1.

Comment: Why are you using encoding when serializing?  It is not needed.  The xml is UTF-8 which will not change any characters (except 0x80).  Using ISO-8859-1 will modify the characters.  For code to work you must to the reverse from what you did in creating the file.  So use XmlReaderSettings = new XmlReaderSettings(); settings.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(filename, settings)

Comment: Is the part 'I have to sign an XML and this returns error "Invalid CAF sign"' done with .NET code? Can you show that code?

Comment: @MartinHonnen  i'll try your link, thanks. I get error "Invalid CAF sign"  when i send this XML to the government institution and they answer me by email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(tempFilePath, settings))
{
      XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());                                                  
      s.Serialize(xmlWriter, obj, ns);
}
```

you will need to wrap an existing XmlWriter into your own one that changes the serialization of `"` and `'` to use entity references `&quot;` and `&apos;`:

```
using (EscapeQuotesXmlWriter exw = new EscapeQuotesXmlWriter(XmlWriter.Create(tempFilePath, settings)))
{
      XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());                                                  
      s.Serialize(exw , obj, ns);
}
```

The class can be implemented as a subclass of `XmlWrappingWriter`

```
public class EscapeQuotesXmlWriter : XmlWrappingWriter
{
    public EscapeQuotesXmlWriter(XmlWriter baseWriter) : base(baseWriter)
    {
    }

    public override void WriteString(string text)
    {
        foreach (char ch in text)
        {
            if (ch == '"')
            {
                WriteEntityRef("quot");
            }
            else if (ch == '\'')
            {
                WriteEntityRef("apos");
            }
            else
            {
                base.WriteString(ch.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    public override void WriteChars(char[] buffer, int index, int count)
    {
        WriteString(new String(buffer.Where((ch, pos) => pos >= index && pos < index + count).ToArray()));
    }

}
```

`XmlWrappingWriter` is part of the project https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=mvpxml still available on the archived Codeplex web site, I am not sure there is a newer or more up to date version somewhere. The one I downloaded there seems to have some `Guard.ArgumentNotNull(value, "value");` checks you might need to replace or comment out.

Note that this code will ensure any `"` or `'` is written out out as the corresponding entity reference, I don't think there is a way to preserve the input format in a deserialization/serialization step.

As for your comment and edit, if you replace `doc.Save(filePath);` with another use of that writer e.g.

```
using (EscapeQuotesXmlWriter exw = new EscapeQuotesXmlWriter(XmlWriter.Create(filePath)))
{
   doc.Save(exw);
}
```

I suppose you should have wanted format.

Comment: Thanks. Awesome, this works for serialization! But when i sign the XML, the characters are replaced. My question was updated.

Comment: @GonzaloBustamante, the `Save` method is another serialization where the normal .NET framework doesn't use entity references for double or single quotes in elements as they are not needed, but you can of course use that "EscapeQuotesXmlWriter` there as well.